How can I determine the radius of convergence of Laplace transform without explicit computations in general?
I’ve been working on problems involving the computation of Laplace transforms and determining their radius of convergence.
For example, while computing the Laplace transform of
$
\sinh(\omega t) = \frac{e^{\omega t} - e^{-\omega t}}{2},
$
using the formula:
$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, dt,
$
I found the transform to be:
$
\mathcal{L}\{\sinh(\omega t)\}(s) = \frac{\omega}{s^2 - \omega^2},
$
with the radius of convergence determined by $|\omega| < s $.
My question is: do I always need to explicitly compute the Laplace transform to determine the radius of convergence, or is there a more efficient way to determine the radius of convergence directly?
I’m working with a reference sheet containing standard Laplace transforms and their properties. I’m wondering if there’s a way to use these properties to determine the radius of convergence without performing the full computation every time.

I don't know if there's anything general that can be said about the radius of convergence (from zero, I guess).  For Laplace transforms it's more natural to consider the abscissa of convergence, i.e. $\Re(s) > c$, where $c$ can be determined by $f(t) = O(\mathrm e^{ct})$, $t\to\infty$.
